# Mock method on a Mock Object in Spock

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I have the following class which i am trying to mock using spock:

```
final class A{
    private B b
    public getB(){
       return b
    }
    public A(B b){
       this.b = b
    }
}
```

and I tried to mock this class using following code and it is working.

```
def "test"(){
    def mockA = GroovyMock(A)
    when:
    service.x()
    then:
    1 * new A(*_) >> {mockA}
}
```

Below is my x() method:

```
x(){
 A a = new A(b)
 B b = a.getB()
}
```

Now I want to mock a.getB() to get a mock object for B. I tried to create a mock for B but I am getting null at a.getB(). Is it possible to mock the getB() method to get a mock Object for B?

So I want to do some thing like

```
1 * a.getB() >> {mockB}
```

but I am getting null exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194523/can-spock-mock-a-java-constructor

Answer (score 0):

do

`def mockA = GroovyMock(A) >> {
  getB() >> GroovyMock(B)
}`.

P.S. I am surprised mocking a constructor of A works without specifying `global: true`

Comment: Yes, a spy is definitely required with global as true. But I was still getting the error with above code. Finally I changed my original code to favor the unit tests.