# Spock for testing Java in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

I have a problem with start testing java code with spock. When I run test there is an error:

```
0 test classes found in package '<default package>'
Process finished with exit code -2
Empty test suite.
```

I use Intellij and Maven, put dependencies into pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>mySecondArg</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

created my simple class `Person`: (in java)

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String age;

    public Person(String name, String surname, String age){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and test (it is spock class):

```
class PersonTest {

    def "my Test"(){
        when:
            Person person = new Person(name: name, surname: surname, age: age)
        then:
            person.name == name
            person.surname == surname
            person.age == age
        where:
            name    |   surname |   age
            "AAA"   |   "BBB"   |   22
            "HHH"   |   "CCC"   |   30
            "BBB"   |   "SSS"   |   40
    }
}
```

my project tree looks like:

[image]

I tried following a few tutorials but probably I missed something. What is problem with my project and why test doesn't work?

Comment: Could you share the complete pom to look into the list of all plugins and dependencies used. Also what `mvn` command did you use to build?

Comment: do have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194523/can-spock-mock-a-java-constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your test should `extends Specification`

```
class PersonTest extends Specification {
```

You are writing your test in Groovy so best practice is to keep them in **src/test/groovy**

Comment: It helps a lot, test works! There is one more problem `Groovyc: unable to resolve class Person`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Two things -

1. Make sure your pom.xml has the mandatory plugin as mentioned at the [official sample](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/pom.xml)

   ```
   <!-- Mandatory plugins for using Spock -->
   <plugin>
     <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin, visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
     <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
     <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.4</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <goals>
           <goal>compile</goal>
           <goal>testCompile</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. All your tests should extend `spock.lang.Specification` as also suggested by [@Bhushan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41912016/1746118)

   ```
   import spock.lang.Specification

   class PersonTest extends Specification {
   ```

***Useful link*** - [Spock Official Eaxmple](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/)

Comment: It is correct to use `Person person = new Person("a","b","c")`? I have an error `unable to resolve class Person`

Comment: @barmi - could you detail the failure and would also suggest to follow on different thread for consequent failures.