# how to mock a new class() call in groovy spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have a method to test which calls a class with new at runtime, how do I mock the same:

```groovy
public class Test {
  public List<Long> method() {
    List<Long> result = (List<Long>) someService.getDetails("select query", new SomeClass(), param)
  }
}
```

How do I mock this line and get result , something like following in groovy:

```groovy
(List<Long>) someService.getDetails("select query", new SomeClass(), param) >> list
```

Doing the following doesn't work:

```groovy
@SpringBean
private SomeClass someClass=Mock()

given:
new SomeClass() >> someClass
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194523/can-spock-mock-a-java-constructor?

Comment: As per this link, I tried following :
def someClass = GroovySpy(SomeClass.class,global: true);
new someClass() >> someClass

someService.getDetails("select query", new SomeClass(), param) >> list
but In actual code it always creates a new SomeClass() and hence returns null

Comment: Your question is tagged both _java_ and _groovy_, so I don't know if your class under test is really Groovy or Java. As documented, Spock's `GroovySpy`, `GroovyMock` etc. only have special behaviour for Groovy target classes. For other JVM classes (Java, Kotlin etc.) they behave like normal Spock mocks. And besides, instead of writing complicated tests you should refactor your code to be easily testable. Designs with loose coupling and injectable dependencies are easier to test, to maintain and to refactor at the same time.

Comment: My code is in java. I am testing java class using Groovy spock

Comment: Do you actually want to mock the constructor of `SomeClass` or do you want to mock a call to `someService.getDetails` to return a list? If it is the latter then, you were pretty close the correct syntax would be `someService.getDetails("select query", _ as SomeClass, param) >> list`. You could also replace `param` with `_`  if you don't really care about the contents. See http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints for more details on how argument matching works.